# commons-image extract info from icctag class

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm using commons-images to extract TIFF / JPG images metadata.

I know this lib cannot be considered as "stable", but this is the best alternative i've found already.

Previously, our app was using imagemagick with a system call, which was really bad in terms of performances.

But I got a problem with ICC profiles.

I would like to extract the data property from a particular IccTag (where itdt is "DESC_TYPE") using a similar code :

```
IccProfileParser iccParser = new IccProfileParser();
IccProfileInfo iccProfileInfo = iccParser.getICCProfileInfo(metadataItem.get().getTiffField().getByteArrayValue());

for(IccTag tag : iccProfileInfo.getTags()) {
    //not getters in tag !
    LOG.debug(tag);
}
```

But that's not natively possible to do so, because this class has no getters..

I've extracted the commons-image source to modify IccTag class with getters.. Is there a better way ?

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/imaging/icc/IccTag.html